# PCRE - Negative Lookahead

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to match whole lines, here an example set:

```
/jome/stat/d-heme-sdfsdf/ertert ***# NOT wanted***
/jome/stat/d-heme-sdfsdf # WANTED
/jome/stat/d-gome-sdfsdf/qeqwe # NOT wanted
```

So I did:

```
(e|d|b)-(heme|gome|jome)-(.+)(?!\/)
```

Unfortunatly, it still matches the unwanted lines. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't require negative lookahed. `.` was matching `/` as well.

```
(e|d|b)-(he|go|jo)me-[^\/]+$
```

Comment: Still matches the unwanted ones

Comment: @royskatt now it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use negative lookahead then place it before `(.+)` and don't forget to add `.*?` inside the negative lookahead.

```
(e|d|b)-(heme|gome|jome)-(?!.*?\/)(.+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sR3vQ4/2)